# Экспериментальный Android NDK новых Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

Только не скажу, с какой версии это выбивает, так как давно не пользовался студией, но при попытке собрать проект выбивает

```
Error:(13, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

Все доходчиво и ясно, и следует вопрос: стоит ли сейчас приступать к работе с этим экспериментальным плагином? Кто уже работал с ним, какие возникали трудности или есть улучшения, по сравнению с предыдущим?

Answer (score 1):

Если при импорте возникнет ошибка `NDK integration is deprecated…`, для её исправления в корневой папке проекта нужно создать файл `gradle.properties` и записать в него строку `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`.

https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/how-to-set-up-fmod-cocos2d-x-and-openal-libraries-for-android-on-intel-architecture